# pytorch/cpp_extension.py path error

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

During the installing of pytorch/audio an external library that builds of off pyTorch it is necessary to run this [setup.py](https://github.com/pytorch/audio/blob/master/setup.py). The program was run with the argument "install" from a fully updated Anacond5.2 with python3.6 terminal on windows10:

[image: command]

The following error output was generated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from torch.utils.cpp_extension import BuildExtension, CppExtension
  File "C:\Users\jason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 59, in <module>
    CUDA_HOME = _find_cuda_home() if torch.cuda.is_available() else None
  File "C:\Users\jason\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 30, in _find_cuda_home
    if not os.path.exists(cuda_home):
  File "C:\Users\jason\Anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py", line 19, in exists
    os.stat(path)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not list
```

*NOTE: path is user specific and usually not needed information, however in this case the error MAY be path related so it is included.*

Answer (score 0):

Please try to execute provided command in installation docs of pytorch.

[pyTorch](https://pytorch.org/#pip-install-pytorch)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I received the following output.

Comment: can you please try this two commands, it seems like a problem with CUDA or CPU packages.

conda install pytorch cuda91 -c pytorch 
pip3 install torchvision

Comment: Thank you again for the help, I executed the first command without issue. However the second command failed with this code: https://snag.gy/a4wMRJ.jpg

Comment: I will follow the instructions from the print out and install with miniconda.

Comment: I think issue 566 answer you question. Its just sequence pf package installation which is creating problem.